# Is it possible to place Cypress tests in existing React file architecture

Tags: reactjs, config, cypress

I know that their patterns say to place all Cypress tests/integrations in the `cypress/integration` path. However, I would like to place the tests in the `src/components` path.

```
src
 └── components
      └── Component1Directory
            ├── Component1.js
            └── tests 
                └── cypress_integration_for_component_1.js

      └───Component2Directory
            ├── Component2.js
            └── tests 
                └── cypress_integration_for_component_2.js
```

I have tried to change the config but wild cards do not seem to work.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4001",
  "integrationFolder": "src/components/*/tests"
}
```

I also tried removing the test sub dir using a wild card in place of "tests" but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the file name to be

```
*.cy.js
```

and updated the config to be

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4001",
  "integrationFolder": "src/",
  "testFiles": "**/*.cy.js"
}
```

This allows the tests to be found in the existing file structure.